# Waiting for input from script that is running remotely via ssh

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh

There is a script I'm running that I can not install on the remote machine.

```
clear && printf '\e[3J'
        read -p "Please enter device: " pattern
        read -p "Enter date: (YYYY-MM-DD): " date
        pfix=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 5 | head -n 1)
        mkdir /home/user/logCollectRes/"${pfix}"
        ssh  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'bash -s' < /usr/local/bin/SearchAdvanced.sh ${pattern} ${date} ${pfix}
```

In that script, I would like to be able to use read.

```
ls -g *"${pattern}"* 

read -p "Select one of these? [y/n] " "found";
```

I've tried adding the -n on the read as well as the -t -t option on ssh. As you can see the script presents information that is only seen once the script starts, so I can't use the read on local machine.

EDIT: So lets say server B stores syslogs for 5K computers. The file names are given by using the internal IP of the device and the date at the end.

```
/var/log/remotes/192.168.1.500201505050736.gz
/var/log/remotes/192.168.1.500201505050936.gz
/var/log/remotes/192.168.1.500201505051136.gz
/var/log/remotes/192.168.1.600201505050836.gz
/var/log/remotes/192.168.1.600201505051036.gz
/var/log/remotes/192.168.1.600201505051236.gz
```

I'd like to be able to select the IP address from the main script, list all the files matching that IP address, and then select which I want to scp to my local machine.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are trying to do here. More specifically what are the `${pattern}`/etc. variables supposed to be doing in that location? (They aren't arguments to the `SearchAdvanced.sh` script because that isn't being run locally. They aren't arguments to the remote `bash` because they are in the wrong place for that. etc.)

Answer (score 0):

After speaking with some coworkers I found the answer to be running two scripts: The first pulls the ls -g result and directs the answer to a variable on the local machine. I then print that output with the read option of selecting on of the files. The 2nd script will take that answer and scp the file from the remote machine

In the main script

```
ssh  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'bash -s' < /usr/local/bin/SearchAdvanced.sh ${pattern} ${date} > ${result}
```

then as a follow up

```
printf "${result}"

read -p "Select file: "
```